# Multiple Prices based on User in Craft Commerce

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

This is my first time using Craft Commerce.  I have a client which needs to have multiple prices for a product.  Customers are in one of three price level groups.  Each price level group has a price unique to them as a variant.  How do I get only the one variant for the appropriate price?

Here is what I tried, but returned all the variants for each price level instead of just one.

```
                <select name="purchasableId">
                    {% set purchasable = craft.commerce.products %}
                    {% for purchasable in product.variants %}
                        <option 
                            {% if purchasable.stock <= 0 and purchasable.unlimitedStock == false %}disabled {% endif %} 
                            value="{{ purchasable.purchasableId }}">

                                Product Number: {{ product.stockDescription1 }} | 
                                Price: 

                                {% if currentUser.isInGroup( 'priceLevelOne' ) %}

                                    {% set variant = craft.commerce.variants %}
                                    {% for variant in product.variants %}
                                        {% if variant.priceLevel1 == 1 %}
                                            Product Number: {{ product.stockDescription1 }} |
                                            Price:
                                            {{ variant.price|currency(cart.currency) }}
                                        {% endif %}
                                    {% endfor %}

                                {% elseif currentUser.isInGroup( 'priceLevelTwo' ) %}

                                    {% set variant = craft.commerce.variants %}
                                    {% for variant in product.variants %}
                                        {% if variant.priceLevel1 == 2 %}
                                            Product Number: {{ product.stockDescription1 }} |
                                            Price:
                                            {{ variant.price|currency(cart.currency) }}
                                        {% endif %}
                                    {% endfor %}


                                {% elseif currentUser.isInGroup( 'priceLevelThree' ) %}

                                    {% set variant = craft.commerce.variants %}
                                    {% for variant in product.variants %}
                                        {% if variant.priceLevel1 == 3 %}
                                            Product Number: {{ product.stockDescription1 }} |
                                            Price:
                                            {{ variant.price|currency(cart.currency) }}
                                        {% endif %}
                                    {% endfor %}

                                {% endif %}
                        </option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
```

Comment: You can add custom fields to variants as well, which is what I think you mean by "item." Depending on how you have your products structured you could also create a variant for each custom group which would have the price associated with that and therefore would not effect the checkout flow or having to alter prices of items.

Comment: Yes, I have those custom fields in my variants, but I need to limit which variants are displayed.  Each product will have 5 variants, but I only need one variant depending on what user group.  Right now all five variants are returned on the product page.

Comment: What is the field type on the variant? If you are using categories, you can do a simple `relatedTo` query to get the one you want, I can provide an example below!

Answer (score 3):

User groups are not a `FieldType` so you can create a category that matches the title of the `userGroup` or put the actual category as a field on the `User` and the `Variant`. Then in your template do something like this:

`{% set userGroup = currentUser.userGroup.first() %}`

`{% set variants = craft.commerce.variants.product(product).relatedTo(userGroup) %}`

This would probably be the best way since you aren't reliant on string matching a title to find the correct variants.

Comment: I am new so....

{% if currentUser.isInGroup( 'priceLevelOne' ) %}
     {% set userGroup = currentUser.priceLevel.first() %}
     {% set variant = craft.commerce.variants.product(parts).relatedTo(userGroup) %}
          {% for variant in product.variants %}
               Product Number: {{ variant.sku }} |
               Price:  {{ variant.price|currency(cart.currency) }}
          {% endfor %}



The category group handle is "userGroup".
The category title is "Price Level 1" and the slug is "price-level-1".

The field containing the category is "priceLevel".

What do I have wrong.

Comment: get rid of the conditional about the isInGroup and simply add a category to a user based on their user group. then all you will need is what I provided and sub in your fieldHandle. Also if you are serving this on a product page you should product instead of parts since that is the variable that commerce passes in by default